# How to search text for this specific string format?

Tags: c#, regex, string, blockquote

I want to check if a string contain following format

```
   [QUOTE]
    Test sentence
    [/QUOTE]
```

If that so then I will do this.

```
            string description = dr["description"].ToString();
            description = description.Replace("[QUOTE]", "<blockquote>");
            description = description.Replace("[/QUOTE]", "</blockquote>");
```

This is OK.

but how about this one?

```
[QUOTE=Axio;26]
Test sentence
[/QUOTE]
```

Also In here I want to add blockquote tag and as well as Want to display this text inside the those tags

> "Orginall posted by Axio. Click here"

When you click "Click HEre" you will go to that specific post. So that should be a hyperlink" 26 is the post id

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match whatever is in [QUOTE] and transform it afterward with `Split` on semicolon. Something like this:

```
        var regexPattern = @"\[QUOTE[=]{0,1}([\d\w;]*)\](.|\r|\n)*\[/QUOTE\]";
        var test1 = @"[QUOTE=Axio;26]
            Test sentence
            [/QUOTE]";
        var test2 = @"[QUOTE]
            Test sentence
            [/QUOTE]";

        var regex = new Regex(regexPattern);

        var match = regex.Match(test1);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            if (match.Groups.Count > 1) //matched [QUOTE=...]
                match.Groups[1].Value.Split(';').ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
            else //matched [QUOTE]..
                Console.WriteLine("Matched [QUOTE]");
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("No match"); 
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Many way to do this, for example:

```
 string des = dr["description"].ToString().Replace("\n", "");
 string info[] = des.SubString(des.IndexOf('=') + 1, des.IndexOf(']')).Split(';');
 string name = info[0];
 string id = info[1]
 string sentence = des.SubString(des.IndexOf(']') + 1, des.LastIndexOf('['));
```

when you got this you know what to do. i wrote it by hand, you may need adjust it youself (substring position not sure if need add/sub 1).

Comment: Even when you add so you don't have an ArgumentOutOfRange exception, you need to subtract your starting index to get the substring. And probably use the first occurance of ']' Otherwise you wind up with something like `[0]: "Axio"`  `[1]: "26]Orgina"`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the description text
var description = "[QUOTE=Axio;26]Orginall posted by Axio. Click here[/QUOTE]";
//Get your id
var id = description.Substring(description.IndexOf(";") + 1, description.IndexOf("]") - (description.IndexOf(";") + 1));

//replace with anchor with id and <blockquotes/>
var editedstring = description
     .Remove(description.IndexOf("["), description.IndexOf("]") + 1)
     .Insert(0, "<blockquote><a href=\"#" + id + "\">")
     .Replace("[/QUOTE]", "</a></blockquote>");
```

Result:

```
 <blockquote><a href="#26">Orginall posted by Axio. Click here</a> </blockquote>
```

> Orginall posted by Axio. Click here